# Number of 7-card hands with at least one exact pair?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I checked the related questions [How many ways to get at least one pair in a seven card hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212173/how-many-ways-to-get-at-least-one-pair-in-a-seven-card-hand) and [Dealing a 5 card hand with exactly 1 pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567420/dealing-a-5-card-hand-with-exactly-1-pair), but didn't see an answer to my precise question.

It's easy to count the number of 7-card hands from a 52-card pack with at least one pair or triplet or 4-of-a-kind (quadruplet?): $C(52,7)-4^7C(13,7)$, with the latter term being the number of hands that have no repeated ranks. The fraction of hands with at least one such multiplet is $508027\,/\,643195$ or about $0.790$.

I want the number of hands that have at least one pair that is not also a triplet and not also a quadruplet. Empirically, the fraction of such hands is about $0.738$.

My unsuccessful attempt at a theoretical calculation goes as follows:

There are $52$ choices for the first card. To complete the mandatory pair, take one of the three remaining cards of the same rank and different suits (three choices), and eliminate the remaining two of the same rank, leaving $48$ cards. Draw the remaining five cards in $48!\,/\,43!$ different ways (multiplets in the remaining five are fine). Reckon as equivalent all $7!$ permutations of the total hand, for a final count of

$({52\times{3}\times{48}\times{47}\times{46}\times{45}\times{44}})\,/\,{7!}$

Unfortunately, this is $44519904\,/\,7$, not only non-integer, but yielding a fraction $0.0475$ of $C(52,7)$, much too low.

What is wrong with my counting argument?

What is the right counting argument?

Comment: There are thirteen ranks (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A) and four suits (heart, diamond, club, spade).  You seem to be confusing the names, which makes your argument difficult to follow.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I made the required corrections. Thanks.

Comment: Note:  there was an arithmetic error in my original posted solution.  I have corrected it now.

Comment: I'll note that the corrected theoretical ratio (0.7388171) is closer to my empirical ratio (from repeated million-hand computer runs) than the uncorrected one I looked at yesterday here (I don't remember that number, but I do remember thinking it wasn't as close as I'd like). The closeness of the numbers boosts confidence both in the argument and in the computer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your count multiply counts some combinations but not others. For example, you multiply count $AABBCDE$.  Also you divide by $7!$, but you should only divide by $5!$, to reflect the symmetry between the ways to choose the last five cards (that symmetry does not extend to the pairs).  Note, for illustration, that we can count the hands that have a unique pair, that is hands of the form $AABCDE$ as $13\times \binom 42 \times 4^5\times \binom {12}5=63258624$ which is already $.47283$ of the total.

Here's a way to do the count:

The "bad" hands are of the following types:

No duplicates is $4^7\times \binom {13}7=28114944$.

One triple:  Pattern is $AAABCDE$ so $13\times \binom 43 \times 4^4 \times \binom {12}4=6589440$

One quadruple:  Pattern is $AAAABCD$ so $13 \times 4^3 \times \binom {12}3=183040$

Two triples:  Pattern is $AAABBBC$ so $\binom {13}{2}\times \binom 43^2\times \binom {11}1\times \binom 41=54912$

One Quadruple, One triple:  Pattern is $AAAABBB$ so $13\times 12 \times \binom 43=624$

Thus there are $34949260$ bad hands altogether, so $\boxed{133784560-34949260=98841600}$ good hands.

Using these numbers we get the desired ratio:  $$\frac {98841600}{133784560}=\fbox {.7388171}$$

Comment: Seems straightforward to generalize, also.

Comment: Agreed.  You just need to be able to list the bad patterns....each individual count is straight forward.

Comment: I don't understand the count for 2 triples.

Comment: @trueblueanil  Indeed.  Thanks.  Will, edit now.  Well, it's $\binom {13}2 \times \binom 43^2 \times 11$, no?  I am just waking up so all manner of blunder is possible.

Comment: @user84413 And for the the very good reason that it is wrong.  I (believe I have corrected it now.  Thanks!

Comment: @trueblueanil  I note we are not matching exactly.  When I wake up I'll review my counts.  We're off by a fairly noticeable margin so I expect the error is in one of the larger blocks.

Comment: @trueblueanil  Never mind, it was obvious.  We were both right in the edit...we need both factors, $11$ and $4$ .  With that error corrected we are now matching.

Comment: A comedy of errors!  :)

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your reply, and for looking at this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer to count directly for each "good" pattern, by multiplying two factors,

**[Choose various ranks]$\times$ [Choose suits for chosen ranks]**

$4-2-1: [\binom{13}{1,1,1}][\binom44\binom42\binom41] =41184 $

$3-2-2:[\binom{13}{1,2}][\binom41\binom42^2] =123552$

$3-2-1-1:[\binom{13}{1,1,2}][\binom43\binom42\binom41^2] = 3294720 $

$2-2-2-1: [\binom{13}{3,1}][\binom42^3\binom41]=2471040$

$2-2-1-1-1:[\binom{13}{2,3}[\binom42^2\binom41^3] = 29652480 $

$2-1-1-1-1-1:[\binom{13}{1,5}][\binom42\binom41^5]= 63258624$

Adding up and dividing by $\binom{52}{7}$, we get $\frac{98841600}{133784560}, \approx 0.7388$

Comment: Don't know how an answer got added instead of getting edited !

Comment: @bof: Yea, certainly less tedious !+1 :)

Comment: @trueblueanil Would you be so kind as to explain the notation of binomial coefficients with commas in the lower position, for instance, $\binom{13}{1,1,1}$? I'm not familiar with that notation.

Comment: @trueblueanil Looks like we can be sure to exhaust the possibilities by enumerating the integer partitions of the length of the hand and then building up the rank-counts and suit-counts (I can see a pattern for doing that once I understand the notation). If I have that right, this looks easy to confidently generalize to hands of any length and to mechanize the generalization in a computer program.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, I should have written $\binom{13}{1,1,1,10}$ since the sum of the lower indices of a multinomial coefficient must equal the upper index, but  since expanded, it is $\binom{13}1\binom{12}1\binom{11}1\binom{10}{10}$, the last lower index can always be left out w/o affecting the result.

Comment: Of course, if you intend to computerise, you must use the full form ! An equivalent expression which you might find more convenient is $\frac{13!}{1!1!1!10!}$

Comment: The wikipedia article on multinomials and multinomial coefficients is good https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following solution using the [in-and-out formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) is slightly less tedious.

For $1\le i\le13$ let $A_i$ be the set of all $7$-card hands containing an exact pair of rank $i.$
$$|A_i|=\binom42\binom{48}5.$$
$$|A_i\cap A_j|=\binom42\binom42\binom{44}3\text{ for }i\lt j.$$
$$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|=\binom42\binom42\binom42\binom{40}1\text{ for }i\lt j\lt k.$$
By the in-and-out formula,
$$|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{13}|=\binom{13}1\binom42\binom{48}5-\binom{13}2\binom42\binom42\binom{44}5+\binom{13}3\binom42\binom42\binom42\binom{40}1$$
$$=133559712-37189152+2471040=\boxed{98841600}.$$